# Tensorflow optimizer with negative feedback?

Tags: python, tensorflow, optimization

I am optimizing a `tensorflow` model.  It is not a neural net, I am just using `tensorflow` for easy derivative computations.  In any case, it seems that loss surface has a steep edge somewhere, and my loss will sometimes "pop out" of the local minimum it is currently targeting, the loss will go up a great deal, and the optimizer will go gallivanting off after some other optimum elsewhere.

I want it to not do that thing.  Specifically, I want it to look at the loss, be all like "holy crap that just went up a whole bunch, I'd better backtrack a bit."  Even though the current gradient may want to send it off elsewhere, I want it to "go back" in sense, and continue trying to find the optimum it was previously targeting.  Is there a tensorflow optimizer that has some kind of "negative feedback" in this way?

Answer (score 1):

You may do a forward pass, check the loss, and then do backward if you think the loss is acceptable. In TF 1.x it requires some `tf.cond` and manual calculation and application of gradients. The same in TF 2.0 only the control flow is easier, but you have to use `gradient_tape` and still apply gradients manually.